# A blank space of about height 20pts displaying at bottom in iOS7 when red banner at top hides

Tags: ios, ios7

If we navigate to another page and if microphone is listening then a red colour banner will be shown at top this is  normal behaviour in iOS7. But in my case when that red colour banner hides then a blank space is showing at bottom. I got struck with this weird issue for long when I google it I can't able to find similar issue anywhere. Any help will be appreciated.